# Example of field $K$ s.t. $|K|=p^{n}$ with $n\geq 2$.

Tags: field-theory

Do you have a example of field $K$ s.t. $|K|=p^n$ with $n\geq 2$ ? I know that $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is a field iff $n$ is prime, but since $p^n$ is not prime, what kind of field can be such that $|K|=p^n$. Would 
$$\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$$
a field ? If yes, does a field $K$ s.t. $|K|=p^n$ is necessarily isomorphic to $$\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\times ...\times \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z\ \ ?$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you generate a field of order $p^n$ is to find an polynomial of degree $n$ that is irreducable over $\mathbb Z / p\mathbb Z [x]$, then mod out by the ideal generated by it.   This is a maximal ideal, so modding out gives you a field.

Comment: I don't understand what mean "modding out".

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.   In $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, we have $$(0,1)\times (1,0)=(0,0)$$
and a field cannot have zero divisors.

Comment: Good example. Thank you :-)